# getSelection returns different object in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, getselection

I'm having an issue with Firefox v37 when it comes to editable labels. This works fine in Chrome v41 and IE v11. I'm looking for possible workarounds since I don't expect this to be corrected anytime soon. I do not care about IE; it's just odd to me that it works but FF does not.

There are two issues which only occur in FF.

1) Selecting the label allows you to input text except FF puts the text in the highest contenteditable node. This ruins the ability to format the text unless it's all the same. All the text inside a single label will not necessarily have the same formatting.

2) In both onclick and onmousedown FF returns the highest contenteditable node with an incorrect offset. This prevents me from knowing where the caret is inside of the label. Chrome and IE both return the text object (or at least the text object's parent) and correct offset inside the object.

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ktc8azf2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">
    <label contenteditable="true" onmousedown="console.log(window.getSelection());">
        <p style="font-style: italic;"></p>
    </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#example [contenteditable="true"]:not(:focus) :not(span):only-child:empty::before {
    content: "<Type Label Here>";
}
```